# When is a left module in matrix form over a ring of matrices free?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

This is a past homework question in abstract algebra: "Let $k$ be a field and let $R = k^{n \times n}$.  When is the left $R$-module $k^{n \times r}$ a free module?"  I have a suggested answer (when $r$ divides $n$) but no justification.

I know that the module (let's call it $M$) will be free when we can express it as the direct sum of copies of $R$.  So I want to form something like this:
$$k^{n\times r} = \oplus k^{n \times n}$$
But doesn't this imply we would need $n$ to divide $r$, rather than the reverse, for this to work?

EDIT:  I found a solution that just raises more questions for me.  In this solution they show $R^d \simeq k^{n\times dn}$ by constructing an isomorphism of modules, which works by gluing together $d$ copies of the $R=k^{n \times n}$ matrix.  Wouldn't $R^d=(k^{n \times n})^d$ be an $dn \times dn$ matrix, not $n \times dn$?

Answer (score 1):

Right, $n$ needs to divide $r$. E.g. $2 \times 2$ matrices act freely on $2 \times (2k)$ matrices

$$\begin{pmatrix} * & * \\ * & * \end{pmatrix} \left( \begin{array}{cc|cc|cc|cc} *&*&*&*&*&*&*&* \\ *&*&*&*&*&*&*&* \end{array} \right)$$

Comment: Twenty stars $*$. Almost Xmas!